# R: how to get the definition of an overloaded generic function?

Tags: r

I tried to get definition of the function predict.fastLm, which is an overloaded generic function in RcppArmadillo, but the following code will fail:

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
getFunction('predict.fastLm')
```

On the other hand, it works for predict.lm:

```
getFunction('predict.lm')
```

Can anyone shed some lights on what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is not exported, so simply type the following instead:

```
> RcppArmadillo:::predict.fastLm
function (object, newdata = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(newdata)) {
...
```

If you insist on using `getFunction`, specify the `where` argument:

```
getFunction('predict.fastLm', where = asNamespace('RcppArmadillo'))
```

Comment: glad to know the ::: operator. sorry that i can't upvote the answer: i need to come here often and contribute, ;).

Comment: If you didn't know about `:::` then you should also probably try `getAnywhere(fn_name)` at the console when you need to find a function that is not exported.